# How to read date as string from excel in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, import, datatable, cell

When I import the excel contents to datatable, I read the cell values using

```
cell.CellValue
```

For, date value I'm not getting it properly, some random numbers are getting retrieved in CellValue. Same is the case with Time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try like below. It will help you....

*Convert that value to Double and to date.*

```
double dtvalue = double.Parse(cell.CellValue);
DateTime dateInfo= DateTime.FromOADate(dtvalue );
```

Comment: is it possible to get the column name of that cell?